# How to remove the echo command from the Linux system?

Tags: linux, echo

I removed the file

> /usr/bin/echo

But still the echo commands executes normally after, even though when I execute

```
$ which echo
```

It says that it can't find it.

What else can i do so the echo commands fail to execute and give me the output for command not found. I am doing this for fun and experimenting with Linux not for any specific purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`which` searches for a name in the path. It does not tell you how a shell will interpret a name.

Use `type` instead:

```
$ type echo
echo is a shell builtin
```

Since it's built into this shell, `echo` commands do not use or require an external executable.

In bash (but not in other shells) you can disable builtins with `enable -n`:

```
$ enable -n echo
$ type echo
echo is hashed (/bin/echo)
```

It will now use the external executable instead, if it exists.

Comment: that makes perfect sense now.